# Heat kernel on hyperbolic space

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request

On $\mathbb{R}^n$, the heat kernel $p(t, x, y)$ (for the Laplacian) satisfies the following pointwise bounds: $p(t, x, y) \leq Ct^{-n/2}, x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n, t > 0$. I was wondering if there are similar bounds for the heat kernel on the hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$ too. Possibly this is well-known, but I cannot find a reference that has a proof. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's an explicit formula here: https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~grigor/nog.pdf

Comment: @John So it actually decays even faster than the Euclidean case. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: You can also check: Davies E.B., Mandouvalos N. , Heat kernel bounds on hyperbolic space
and Kleinian groups, Proc. London Math. Soc.(3) , 52 (1988) no.1, 182-
208, where you can find sharp upper and lower bounds for the heat kernel on the hyperbolic space.